# FluentNhibernate: map byte enum as char

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class that has an enum that it's values are ASCII codes.
I want to save in the DB the char value not the ASCII code, How can I achieve that?

Comment: If the values are ASCII codes, why do you use an enum instead of a `char`?

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon Because those ASCII codes has a meaning and you can choose only few ASCII codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own type conversion using `IUserType` interface. Example how to do that can be found [here](http://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype/) or [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/10/15/mapping-different-types-iusertype.aspx).

Once you do that, you have to tell your fluent mapper to use this type for given property:

```
Map(u => u.AsciiCode).CustomType<AsciiCodeAsChar>();
```

Comment: Thanks those two links you gave are awesome, specially the second one.